# Generating slug for users in a table with 1 million users in a short time without affecting db performance in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, database-performance, friendly-id

I want to add a column to my users table and generate slug for all of them. The problem is I have over 1 million users in my DB.

I have seen various blogs explaining different methods but I do not want to take risk by doing it in my production DB.

**Methods that I found:**

1. The below method suggests to add the code to **generate slug in migration** file itself.

   ```
   class AddStatusToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     end

     def up
       add_column :users, :status, :string
       User.find_each do |user|
         user.status = 'active'
         user.save!
       end
     end

     def down
       remove_column :users, :status
     end
   end
   ```
2. I have written this method which is run by a **rake** task:
   The problem with the below one is that it has been running 4 days in which only 400 000 slugs have been generated so far. I wanted to do it quickly, but do not know how.

**[find_in_batches](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_in_batches)**:

> Yields each batch of records that was found by the find options as an
>   array. The size of each batch is set by the :batch_size option; the
>   default is 1000.
>
> You can control the starting point for the batch processing by
>   supplying the :start option. This is especially useful if you want
>   multiple workers dealing with the same processing queue. You can make
>   worker 1 handle all the records between id 0 and 10,000 and worker 2
>   handle from 10,000 and beyond (by setting the :start option on that
>   worker).
>
> It’s not possible to set the order. That is automatically set to
>   ascending on the primary key (“id ASC”) to make the batch ordering
>   work. This also mean that this method only works with integer-based
>   primary keys. You can’t set the limit either, that’s used to control
>   the batch sizes.

In order to avoid DB performance issues I have given a sleep time of 2 seconds after every slug generation for 1000 users. Should I remove the sleep method? Should I just run `User.find_each(&:save)` or method 1?

```
task :add_slug_to_all_users => :environment do
  i=0
  batchSize = 1000
  puts "started at :#{Time.now}"
  # find_in_batches method provides the users in batches of 1000 
  # so that the update is not triggered for all the rows at once which may lock the table completely.
  User.where("slug is null and email is not null").find_in_batches(batch_size: batchSize) do |users|
    sleep(2)
    users.each {|u| u.save!; i+=1;} 
    puts "updated #{i} records at: #{Time.now}"
  end
  puts "Completed the Task at: #{Time.now}\n"
end
```

**Update 1**: I am using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/4.0.10.1) gem to generate slugs.

**Update 2**: I have run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` and I got this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `p_views` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `p_desc` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `p_title` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `t_zone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT 'UTC',
  `college` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `degree` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `p_no` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_phone_number` (`p_no`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_phone_no` (`p_no`),
  UNIQUE KEY `index_users_on_slug` (`slug`),
  KEY `use_index_on_college` (`college`(255))
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2194 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Please note that I have removed most of the fields from the above result. The column `slug` stores the combination of **first_name** and **last_name** in a url friendly manner.

For e.g. if a user's name is:

```
id first_name   last_name
1  Arun         Kumar
2  Arun         Kumar
```

The **slug** generated would look like this:

```
id slug
1  arun-kumar
2  arun-kumar1
```

Comment: You should edit your title and question, lakh (= 100,000) is not used outside of India.

Comment: @MichaelKohl thanks I have changed it to 1 million.

Comment: How your slugs are generated? I think it will be better, if you will update batch of users in a single query.

Comment: @unkmas Do you think the approach defined in Method 2 is fine, should I run multiple rake tasks to finish it quickly will that create any issues?

Comment: @unkmas I am using [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/tree/4.0.10.1) gem for generating slugs.

Comment: I suggest to use an `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction`-Block around the line `users.each {|u| u.save!; i+=1;}` of your rake task. So the database doesn't have to write each single update (`u.save!`). Instead it would combine all updates of a batch in a single commit. Be aware, in case of an exception in `u.save!` there would be no update for the current batch.

Comment: @guitarman thanks, will try this out.

Comment: What version are you using?  5.6 can add the column with little fuss; 5.7 further improves things.

Comment: @RickJames I use version: 5.5. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation like this, all-purpose 3rd party software can only get in the way.  You would be better off going down to the SQL to do the work.

If the "slug" is a simple sequence number, then adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` would be the obvious solution, and a permanent solution.  That is, all future additions would have the slug automatically generated.  That could be done with one statement:

```
ALTER TABLE t
    ADD COLUMN slug INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    INDEX(slug);
```

It would possibly be better for `slug` to be the `PRIMARY KEY`  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)  But that would probably require a serious lock on the table; so a plain index is better.  Test it.  It may be "fast enough".

The next thought is `pt-online-schema-change` (see Percona.com), which is a special tool for effectively doing `ALTERs` with nearly zero impact.  It involves adding a `TRIGGER` to capture writes, and chunking of the copying.  The slight impact comes with the "last little bit" needs to be copied.  The final `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;` is atomic and essentially instantaneous.  It even dynamically tunes the "sleep".  It is an excellent tool with many years of experience put into it.

But, ptosc may not work for adding something as critical as the `PRIMARY KEY`, hence my suggestion (above) of a plain `INDEX`.

Setting the values (via `UPDATE`), one chunk at a time, is the right way to go.  I have written on [*chunking tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks); that was aimed at `DELETE`, but can be adapted to `UPDATE`.

Without knowing what is "under the covers" in `find_in_batches()`, I cannot say that it is good or bad.  I do know that `OFFSET` is almost always bad; "remembering where you left off" is usually much better.  But it is hard to do that if you don't already have a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY` key.  `PRIMARY` is better because of its clustering.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, so I don't have to make guesses.)

If your sample code starts over at the beginning of the table each time, then it is as bad as using `OFFSET` -- each iteration will be slower than the previous because it is skipping over more and more rows.

After adding a column, be sure to check all references to the table -- `SELECT *` will now have one more column (one reason for not using `*`).  `UPDATEs` and `INSERTs` may work with the missing column, but you need to check.

**Update**

There were two steps -- add the `slug` column, and populate it.  You have done the first step.

To do the second step, I recommend stepping through the table 100 rows at a time, using the `AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY`.  100 is low enough to be not-too-invasive.  The AI PK will cover the entire table, and is efficient so that you don't need a slow `OFFSET` or search for un-slugged set.  I discuss efficient chunking [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks).  It is written with `DELETE` in mind, but the techniques apply to `UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I have updated my question with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I am not using offset in my querying( as I read in a blog that it takes more time than normal `limit` operator used in `mysql` ) as I have given a condition to select only those users for whom slug is not generated.

Comment: But it takes time to skip over more and more already-slugged rows.  [_More_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) on remembering where you left off.

Comment: What do you suggest now seeing my case above in the question as I need to generate slug from user's firstname and lastname? I guess this cannot be done through procedures. The above slug generation is a one time process which I have to do as it is a new feature addition, for new users it will be added as and when the users log in again.

Comment: Rick I was saying your answer is the right one and the OP should accept it

Comment: @e4c5 - Thanks.  (I thought you might be referring to some of the comments.)